# How do I list tables in Google BigQuery that match a certain name?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using template-suffix based tables in BigQuery. In order to actually take advantage of these, I need to scope my query to a specific table. Is there a way using legacy, or standard SQL to just list the tables that meet a specific pattern?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check [Metadata about tables in a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#metadata_about_tables_in_a_dataset)
You can do something like below in BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES__
WHERE table_id CONTAINS 'github'
```

Or with BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM publicdata.samples.__TABLES__
WHERE starts_with(table_id, 'github')
```

I just realized that you most likely meant not `How do I list tables that match a certain name?` but rather `How do I query tables that match a certain name?`

In BigQuery Standard SQL - you can use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` and in BigQuery Legacy SQL you can use `TABLE_DATE_RANGE()` or `TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT()` or `TABLE_QUERY()`

You should check [Querying Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) for more details